# What's the counter for seasons?

Tags: counters

I want to say, "the third season is fall".

Comment: Downvoter explain yourself :0

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this japanese.SE is not a translation service, so people like it when you give it a shot. Suggested reading: http://www.sanabo.com/kazoekata/ct_ka/ki/kisetsu/

Comment: Valid question!  I'm sure there is a very japanese-y answer, but I'm unaware of one myself.  You could say the third season 第三季節 (dai san ki setsu)

Comment: You show zero effort, so why should the downvoter show more? Besides, there is no need for a counter to say what you wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seasons can be a little tricky because they mean different things.

When talking about the four astronomical/meteorological seasons as in your example, it is probably most natural to use a generic counter: 3つ目の季節は秋です.

Ways of counting other seasons:

- 第3シーズン、3シーズン目 (For sports, orchestras, theatre, TV shows, business seasons)
- 第3季、3季目 (For sports, business seasons)
- 第3期、3期目 (Generic counter for periods of time, except not used to count the four astronomical/meteorological seasons.)

Comment: 期 is also used for anime "seasons", basically sets of 13 episodes or thereabouts.